# Instal Ubuntu to w2k machine

Tags: 11.04, wubi, live-usb

I have a dilapidated PC at home i want to turn turn into a server (probably with debian on it in the end). My first thoughts were to install Ubuntu through the live-boot USB but for some reason, I cannot get it to boot properly, I can tell the machine to boot from USB, and i can see a line that is familiar from the install process, but it  does not proceed further...

I am unsure if this is because the machine is too old (it is about 8 years old now, although some parts of it have been replaced over time). I haven't tried burning to a disc yet, i shall try that later, but some suggestions would be nice as to what i am doing wrong...

**some further details**:

- No OS on the machine currently, was originally running w2000
- Distribution matches instruction-set
- Tried installing redhat a while back, couldnt get it to install correctly either (x-org wouldn't configure)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from your question is that you are attempting to boot an an 8 years or older x86-32 (aka i386) computer from an 11.04 i386 Live USB drive.

My guess (... and I can't do much more than guess without more specifics about the computer's hardware like a motherboard manufacturer name and model number ...) is that this computer simply cannot boot from a USB drive? Are you able to boot any other operating system on it using USB?

My recollection is that booting from USB was very much a '*hit or miss*' function when it first appeared. A computer could appear to support USB boot by providing an entry for USB Boot in the BIOS or boot menu, but, when tried, it would not work.

Your plan to burn a Live CD and boot from it is also what I would recommend.

If you do this and want more help, please edit/update your original question with any new or additional details. (Stack Exchange encourages [**using the comments for only short remarks**](https://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask). I believe the intent is to avoid requiring a reader to hunt through every comment to know enough to provide a pertinent answer.)

One more thing. You have attached the [wubi](/questions/tagged/wubi) tag to your question. Why??? I am unable to see what connection Wubi might have to your question.